# Google Maps Api v3: different markers and polyline sizes depending on zoom level

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

Is it possible to show a different image marker depending on the zoom level?

I would like to show smaller markers if the zoom level is lower.

I would also like to know if it's possible to change the thickness of the polylines depending on the zoom level.

I guess it all depends on the possibility to set a listener for the zoom event.

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Map):
**zoom_changed**    :   This event is fired when the map zoom property changes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. by listening to the zoom_changed event you can then carefully reset the overlay options (icon, color...).